# Visual Studio 2015 is crashing after modify and save EDMX changes on the development system

Tags: visual-studio-2015, edmx

I am getting the below code when updating EDMX on Visual Studio 2015.

```
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.8.4645.0, time stamp: 0x648f709e
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0002fff1
Faulting process id: 0x5508
Faulting application start time: 0x01da0001bb3db1bb
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 9069314d-70ec-40a0-aa6c-ab30c63c4200
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```